# UITextView check whether text field is empty or not in Objective-C

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, uitextview

i have `UITextView` which is inside the `tableview` `cell`, and when i click on the "NO" option , the cell will expand , i need to pass the both text which is entered in the `textview` and image which is uploaded here,

But the problem is am not able to validate the `textview`, whether it is empty or not,

i should check whether it is empty or not, and if it is empty is need to alert the message.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the table view cell containing your text as a custom table view cell.  When you do that, you can connect your UITextView to an outlet.

Once you do that, it's easy to check by simply looking at the length of the [`.text` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview/1618623-text) for that outlet.

e.g. something like:

(for Swift):

```
if myTextView.text.characters.count > 0
{
   // there is something in here
}
```

Comment: i have not created any outlet

Comment: Since this is a custom table cell (as you've added items to it), you can certainly create an outlet to go with it.  :-)  Also, a good iOS question on [so] should state which language you're using.

Comment: Can be checked like that without outlet as well.

Comment: i know how to create outlet out side, but i dont know how to create how create it for an item which is inside the table view cell

Comment: Of course @LoVo, I was just helping to drive the o.p. to a hopefully easier solution.

Comment: am I correct in guessing that the screenshot I see up there is a collection of various prototype cells?  If so, where does the content for UITextView come from?  Why not try to get the text length on whatever feeds the cell that contains the text view?

Comment: @Purushothaman, sub-class a UITableViewCell class and set the outlet over there, then reuse that table cell. From cell property you can access the text view

Comment: @sailendrak. ok